# How do I simplify $34\csc{\frac{2\pi}{17}}$?

Tags: trigonometry, fractions, nested-radicals, rationalising-denominator

I have $$ 34\csc\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{17}\right)$$ is equal to $$\dfrac{136}{\sqrt{8-\sqrt{15+\sqrt{17} +  \sqrt{34 + 6\sqrt{17} - \sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17} } + 2\sqrt{ 578-34\sqrt{17}} - 16\sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}    }  }}}.$$

I want to rationalize it, but I am not sure where to start. Could anyone provide an explanation on how to rationalize this, and what should the answer be?

Comment: What is this relevant to? The only thing I can think of is constructing a $34$-gon or something like that

Comment: See this: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/rationalize-denominator-calculator/rationalize%20denominator%20%5Cfrac%7B136%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B8-%5Csqrt%7B15%2B%5Csqrt%7B17%7D%20%2B%20%20%5Csqrt%7B34%20%2B%206%5Csqrt%7B17%7D%20-%20%5Csqrt%7B34-2%5Csqrt%7B17%7D%20%7D%20%2B%202%5Csqrt%7B%20578-34%5Csqrt%7B17%7D%7D%20-%2016%5Csqrt%7B34-2%5Csqrt%7B17%7D%7D%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%7D%7D%7D%20   . Although denominator isn't completely rationalized but it looks much better.

Comment: If anyone may find this helpful (sourced from a deleted answer from this post), $\csc\dfrac{\pi}{17} = \dfrac{\sqrt{233489}+627}{6}$. Whoever deleted their answer, it would be appreciated if you put your answer as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

$$\csc^2\left(\frac{2\pi}{17}\right)=\frac{1}{17}\left[102+17\sqrt{17}-17\frac{\sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}}{2}-17\frac{\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}}{2}+\sqrt{17}\cdot \sqrt{A}\right]$$
$$A=850+204\sqrt{17}-143{\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}}-113{\sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}}$$
$$\tan^2\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{17}\right)=5+3\sqrt{17}+5\frac{\sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}}{2}+5\frac{\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}}{2}-\sqrt{A}$$
$$A=850+204\sqrt{17}+161{\sqrt{34+2\sqrt{17}}}+127{\sqrt{34-2\sqrt{17}}}$$

Comment: Yes, this does help, but how did you get this, and what is the complete value of $\csc{\dfrac{2\pi}{17}}$?

Comment: $$\csc\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{17}\right)=\sqrt{\csc^2\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{17}\right)}$$

Comment: Yes, I know that. Is there any other useful information that you can provide? This does not really answer the question. Also, $\tan x + \cot x = \dfrac{\tan^2 x + 1}{\tan x} =  2 \csc 2x$ so maybe that identity helps.